# SSL errors logging for non HTTPS site

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I have `http://example.com` without HTTPS enabled (I'm not allowed by the client to enable SSL). I noticed some links with HTTPS like

```
https://example.com/sslsecured-content
```

on the internet to the site. I track all traffic with PHP script inside pages. But when HTTPS request comes - my page is not opened (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID) and the event is not logged. How can I log https traffic errors?

I'm wondering maybe I can solve this by redirecting HTTPS to HTTP with `.htaccess` if that is possible.

Namecheap shared hosting is used for the site.

Comment: Ideally you should convince you client that not using SSL in 2019 is utterly moronic, but aside from that the only solution would be running a site with a valid certificate for the client's domain that does nothing but redirect to not-SSL, which is one of the dumbest, most backwards things I've ever said on this site.

Comment: You can do neither of those things on the HTTP level, or anything that comes after that (PHP scripts, ...) - the browser does break of its attempts _before_ it and the server even start to speak HTTP to each other. Establishing the secure connection happens _before_ HTTP.

Comment: "not allowed by the client to _enable_ SSL" - You could _enable_ it, but still not actively use it? (You need to _enable_ it in order to log or redirect it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no valid certificate you can't redirect to http because the client block the request. So you have to install a valid certificate. In actual times with Let's encrypt that shouldn't be a problem and TLS is a standard that every page should have and have to be used for DSGVO in the Europe countries.

Answer (score 0):

In short answer: no, since "http" and "https" are different protocols, so you can't track "https" requests from "http" protocol.